# Neovim python3 support not working

Tags: neovim

I have problems getting python3 support working in neovim. 
I have followed the instructions in `:help nvim-python`, but `:echo has('python3')` returns 0.

I have tried installing the neovim python modules both from git and pip, and also the AUR on arch linux, but `:echo has('python3')` still returns 0.

I tried setting the path to python manually in neovim, and I also tried rebuilding neovim from source from github after installing python modules, but still nothing.

Edit: I found out clipboardprovider didn't work either.

Comment: I don't get anything for `:help nvim-python`. I believe the instructions are now at `:help provider-python`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I found out there was an error in my init.vim. I was overwriting the runtimepath instead of appending to it.

I had this line:

```
set runtimepath=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after
```

Change to this:

```
set runtimepath+=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after
```

And then it works.